# Dynamic number of fields in table

Tags: t-sql

I have a problem with TSQL. I have a number of tables, each table contain different number of fielsds with different names.

I need dynamically take all this tables, read all records and manage each record into string list, where each value separated by commas. And do smth. with this string.

I think that I need to use CURSORS, but I can't FETCH em without knowing A concrete amount of fields with names and types. Maybe I can create a table variable with dynamic number of fields?

Thanks a lot!

Makarov Artem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would repurpose one of the many T-SQL scripts written to generate INSERT statements. They do exactly what you require. Namely

1. Reverse engineer a given table to determine columns names and types
2. Generate a delimited string of values

The most complete example I've found is [here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts)

But just a simple Google search for "INSERT STATEMENT GENERATOR" will yield several examples that you can repurpose to fit your needs.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   ORDINAL_POSITION
  ,COLUMN_NAME
  ,DATA_TYPE
  ,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
  ,IS_NULLABLE
  ,COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM   
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   
  TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE' 
ORDER BY 
  ORDINAL_POSITION ASC;
```

from http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/04/27/60574.aspx

Comment: I'd use an object in my application to represent the table after retrieving the resultset from the above query.  If you want to do this in pure SQL I don't know enough to answer meaningfully.

Comment: Unfortunately, I use only pure SQL. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do something with this.

```
select T2.X.query('for $i in * 
                   return concat(data($i), ",")'
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as C
from (
      select *
      from YourTable
      for xml path('Row'),elements xsinil, type
     ) as T1(X)
  cross apply T1.X.nodes('/Row') T2(X)
```

It will give you one row for each row in `YourTable` with each value in `YourTable` separated by a comma in the column `C`.

This builds an XML for the entire table and then parses that XML. Might get you into trouble if you have tables with a lot of rows.

BTW: I saw from a comment that you can "use only pure SQL". I really don't think this qualifies as "pure SQL" :).

Comment: Hah! Thank you :) But I can't even understand it :) I already do it.. It was very hard :)